# DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL don't work inside a PROCEDURE

Tags: oracle, plsql

I create a script to copy a table from DEVBASE user:

```
DECLARE
  YTABLE_NAME   CONSTANT VARCHAR2 (50) := 'TABLE_NAME';
  YRECREATE     CONSTANT BOOLEAN       := FALSE;
--
  XCOMMAND               CLOB;

  FUNCTION TABLE_EXISTS (ZTABLE_NAME IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN BOOLEAN IS
    XCOUNT   NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT (*)
      INTO XCOUNT
      FROM USER_TABLES A
     WHERE A.TABLE_NAME = ZTABLE_NAME;

    RETURN XCOUNT > 0;
  END;
BEGIN
  IF TABLE_EXISTS (YTABLE_NAME) THEN
    IF YRECREATE THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || YTABLE_NAME || ' CASCADE CONSTRAINTS';
    ELSE
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000, 'TABLE ' || YTABLE_NAME || ' ALREADY EXISTS');
    END IF;
  END IF;

  DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM (DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM, 'SQLTERMINATOR', FALSE);
  DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM (DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM, 'PRETTY', FALSE);
  DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM (DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM, 'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES', FALSE);
  DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM (DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM, 'STORAGE', FALSE);
  DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM (DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM, 'EMIT_SCHEMA', FALSE);
  DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM (DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM, 'SEGMENT_CREATION', FALSE);
  DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM (DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM, 'CONSTRAINTS_AS_ALTER', FALSE);
  XCOMMAND := DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL ('TABLE', YTABLE_NAME, 'DEVUSER');

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE XCOMMAND;
END;
```

It works, but if I create a procedure with this code, I got a error "ORA-31603: object {table name} of type TABLE not found in schema DEVUSER".

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE COPY_TABLE (YTABLE_NAME IN VARCHAR2, YRECREATE IN BOOLEAN) IS
BEGIN
  -- exact same code
END;
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: It's because procedures don't use user priviledges granted through roles. I think dev_user can get the code since `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` is granted but that doesn't help in the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle [Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm#i1016867) states:

> In stored procedures, functions, and
>   definers-rights packages, roles are disabled.
>   Therefore, **such a PL/SQL program can
>   only fetch metadata for objects in its
>   own schema**. If you want to write a
>   PL/SQL program that fetches metadata
>   for objects in a different schema
>   , you must make
>   the program invokers-rights.

To do this, you must add `authid` to your procedure.